# How to determine that style supports custom control element

Tags: qt

I have implemented a custom widget and introduced new control element CE_MYShapedFrame. Now my widget is not working with standard styles because they are not aware about CE_MYShapedFrame. I need to change my widget to work with standard styles.

```
void MyWidget::paintEvent(QPainter* painter)
{
    if (this->style()->supports(CE_MYShapedFrame) {
        style->drawControl(CE_MYShapedFrame, &opt, painter);
    } else 
        style->drawControl(CE_ShapedFrame, &opt, painter);
    }
}
```

So my question is:
Is there a way to write condition like if (this->style()->supports(CE_MYShapedFrame).

Comment: Your `paintEvent()` signature is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You know that standard Qt styles don't support this. But your custom style will. So, you can simply check if it is your style:

```
if (dynamic_cast<MyStyle>(style()) {
  style()->drawControl(CE_MYShapedFrame, &opt, painter);
} else {
  style()->drawControl(CE_ShapedFrame, &opt, painter);
}
```

If you expect there to be multiple styles that can support it, you can introduce a common interface, and check for its presence at runtime.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QStyle>
#include <QStyleOption>
#include <QEventLoop>

class IClever {
public:
    virtual bool supports(QStyle::ControlElement) = 0;
    static IClever * cast(QStyle * style) {
        return dynamic_cast<IClever*>(style);
    }
};

class MyStyle : public QStyle, public IClever {
    bool supports(QStyle::ControlElement el) { }
    //...
};

enum { kCE_MYShapedFrame };
QStyle::ControlElement CE_MYShapedFrame() {
    return (QStyle::ControlElement)kCE_MYShapedFrame;
}

class MyWidget : public QWidget {
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent*) {
        QStyleOption opt;
        opt.initFrom(this);
        QPainter painter(this);
        if (IClever::cast(style()) && IClever::cast(style())->supports(CE_MYShapedFrame())) {
            style()->drawControl(CE_MYShapedFrame(), &opt, &painter);
        } else {
            style()->drawControl(QStyle::CE_ShapedFrame, &opt, &painter);
        }
    }
};
```